# Как можно принять (получить) письмо через php и mysql?

Tags: php, email

Как можно принять (получить) письмо через `php` и `mysql`? А отправляется письмо через функцию `mail();`

```
<?php
$to = "receiver@domain.com";
$subject = "This is a test mail";
$message = "Hi! This is a simple text mail to test";
$from = "sender@a2zwebhelp.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($result==true){
   echo "Mail Sent successfully.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принять письмо через mysql невозможно в принципе, а через PHP - это надо **очень** сильно постараться.

Принимать письма должен **почтовый сервер**. А из РНР к нему можно обратиться, с помощью функций [imap](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php)